# WSO2 EI log about Java heap space

Tags: wso2

I have called an endpoint and it response a large data, unfortunately show the error message in WSO2 carbon log  . How can I solve it? Thank you.

```
    TID: [-1] [] [2018-02-26 17:48:47,869] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.das.messageflow.data.publisher.data.MessageFlowObserverStore} -  Error occurred while notifying the statistics observer {org.wso2.carbon.das.messageflow.data.publisher.data.MessageFlowObserverStore}
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.flush(Output.java:181)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.require(Output.java:160)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.writeString_slow(Output.java:462)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.Output.writeString(Output.java:363)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$StringSerializer.write(DefaultSerializers.java:191)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$StringSerializer.write(DefaultSerializers.java:184)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:628)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:100)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:628)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:100)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:628)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.write(MapSerializer.java:113)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.write(MapSerializer.java:39)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:534)
    at org.wso2.carbon.das.messageflow.data.publisher.publish.StatisticsPublisher.addEventData(StatisticsPublisher.java:116)
    at org.wso2.carbon.das.messageflow.data.publisher.publish.StatisticsPublisher.process(StatisticsPublisher.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.das.messageflow.data.publisher.observer.DASMediationFlowObserver.updateStatistics(DASMediationFlowObserver.java:55)
    at org.wso2.carbon.das.messageflow.data.publisher.data.MessageFlowObserverStore.notifyObservers(MessageFlowObserverStore.java:71)
    at org.wso2.carbon.das.messageflow.data.publisher.services.MessageFlowReporterThread.processAndPublishEventList(MessageFlowReporterThread.java:225)
    at org.wso2.carbon.das.messageflow.data.publisher.services.MessageFlowReporterThread.run(MessageFlowReporterThread.java:95)
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the out of memory issue it is hard to say anything about the culprit. In order to find out the actual root cause we have to analyze the heapdump (There will heapdump created by wso2 servers automatically in CARBON_HOME/repository/logs/heap-dump.hprof) using an analyzing tool such as [MAT](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/), [jprofile](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html).

However, if the response message is large, there is a possibility that the server goes OOM as it keeps and may build the response message in memory. If you want to process large messages, you can tune the heap memory allocation as in the [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Java+Virtual+Machine+Performance+Tuning).

Comment: My response data size is 11.6 MB. I already set the Heap Memory 4G, it still have the error above. I have analyzed the heapdump also no special. Have any other ideas? Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem on messages with size between 6MB and 15MB